# Prove an identity for the continuous integral solution of the conservation law

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

This is an exercise in Evans, *Partial Differential Equations* (1st edition), page 164, problem 13:

> Assume $F(0) = 0, u$ is a continuous integral solution of the conservation law
>   $$
> \left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
>  u_t + F(u)_x = 0 &\mbox{ in $\mathbb{R} \times (0,\infty)$} \\
>   u=g &\mbox{ on $\mathbb{R} \times \left\{t=0\right\} $} \, ,
>        \end{array} \right.
> $$
>   and $u$ has compact support in $\mathbb{R} \times [0,\infty]$. Prove 
>   $$
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(\cdot,t)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g \,dx
> $$
>   for all $t>0$.

How to solve it?

Comment: Sorry for asking here, but what does the $u(\cdot,t)$ stand for? I've never seen this annotation

Comment: @jigga It denotes the function $x\mapsto u(x,t)$ of the 'dot' variable $x$, where $t$ is viewed as a constant parameter.

Answer (score 7):

Notice that in the equality you want to prove:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(x,\color{red}{t})\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g\, dx,
$$
the left term is a function of the temporal variable while the right term is a real constant assuming that $u(x,0) = g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and is compactly supported as well. If for the moment we assume $u$ is smooth, take the time derivative on the left:
$$
\frac{d}{d\color{red}{t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(x,t)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial \color{red}{t}}u(x,t)\,dx,\tag{1}
$$
where we performed the differentiation under the integral sign for $u$ is smooth. The right side of above is:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(x,t)\,dx = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} F\big(u(x,t)\big)\,dx =- F\big(u(x,t)\big)\Big\vert^{\infty}_{-\infty}=0,
$$
because of $u$ is compactly supported and $F(0) = 0$. Hence
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(x,t)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u(x,0)\, dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g\, dx.
$$
This gives you an idea of why this is called conservation law.

---

Back to the integral solution $u$ of the conservation law (the definition is somewhere earlier in that conservation law chapter of Evans):
$$
\int^{\infty}_0 \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \Big(u v_t + F(u) v_x\Big)\,dxdt + \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}  gv\,dx \big|_{t=0}= 0,\tag{2}
$$
for $v\in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}\times [0,\infty))$. Now $u$ only lies in $L^{\infty}\cap C_c$ (***$u$ may not be differentiable anymore***, thinking all those blows up in time, and shock waves in space!),  the trick in (1) is not applicable anymore, here the way to prove this is to choose proper test function $v$.

Think $u(x,\tau)$ for any $\tau>0$, and consider the problem when the time starts at $\tau$:
$$
\left\{ \begin{aligned} 
 u_t + F(u)_x &= 0 &\text{ in } \mathbb{R} \times (\tau,\infty),  \\
  u&=u(x,\tau)  &\text{ at } \mathbb{R} \times \left\{t=\tau\right\} , 
       \end{aligned} \right.\tag{$\star$}
$$
The weak solution to $(\star)$ coincides with the original IVP **if we assume the solution is unique** (but unfortunately this is not true for the integral solution, that's why we solve for an entropy solution by artificially adding a diffusion perturbation, which is the so-called vanishing viscosity method). Then we can see $u$ satisfies:
$$
\int^{\infty}_{\tau} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \Big(u v_t + F(u) v_x\Big)\,dxdt + \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}  uv\,dx \big|_{t=\tau}= 0,\tag{3}
$$
for $v\in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}\times [\tau,\infty))$ which can be easily extended to the whole time domain smoothly. The difference between (2) and (3) is 
$$
\int^{\tau}_{0} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \Big(u \color{blue}{v_t} + F(u) \color{blue}{v_x}\Big)\,dxdt + \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}  gv\,dx \big|_{t=0} - \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}  uv\,dx \big|_{t=\tau}= 0.\tag{4}
$$
Now you can either argue by (A) the test function makes (2) and (3) together must vanish on $[0,\tau)$, hence the blue terms are gone, or (B) choosing $v = 1$ on a set containing the support of $u$ from $t=0$ to $t=\tau$, and the support of $F(u)$ (notice $F\big(u(x\to \infty,t)\big) = F(0) = 0$, the compactly supportedness of $u$ implies that $F(u)$ is compactly supported), then blue terms are gone as well.

Hence we have by (4): for any $\tau>0$
$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}  gv \,dx \big|_{t=0} =\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}  uv\,dx \big|_{t=\tau}.$$
By the choice of the test function $v$ above in (B), we have
$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}  g(x)  \,dx  =\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}  u(x,\tau)\,dx.$$

Comment: thank you for this answer. Recently I have been looking for a generalization of this statement for solution that do not have necessarily compact support; e.g. the solution for $g(x)=e^{-x^2}$. ([here's the thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2266061/conservation-of-mass-in-hyperbolic-pde-reference-request)). Today I had an idea how to make it work, would you mind taking a look at it?

Comment: Where did you use $F(0)=0$? If you choose $v=1$ then obviously $v_t=v_x=0$ on the domain. I'm not exactly clear on your choice of test functions either. Can you please elaborate on these things a bit more? Since I have just started learning conservation laws and I'm teaching myself using Evans, I'm not well aware about the tricks of the trade. Please be as explicit as you can.

Comment: @mudok, because the test function can not change the boundary behaviors of the solution, either on the temporal boundary or spacial boundary. Thus it has to be smooth and compactly supported (zero on the boundary), that is where the notation $C_c$ comes from, the subscript means "compactly supported". So $v=1$ can not be a test function.

Comment: If I'm not misunderstanding your solution then what I see is that you have taken a compact set $K$ which contains the supports of $u$ and $F$. Since $F(0)=0$ we  see that the supports of $u$  and $F$ are exactly same, say $L$ and $L\subset K$. Now you  chose $v=1$ on $L$ and smoothly extend $v$ on $K$ so that $K$ is now support of $v$. Then $v_t=v_x=0$ on $L$ which concludes the result. Did I understand correctly? Please also explain why did you say we can either argue by (A) or (B).

Comment: @mudok Your understanding is correct. The key is to cook up a smooth test function that gives you the final result. (B) is a specific choice. (A) is a more general argument that we can use smooth test function $v$ such that $v_x=v_t=0$ from $0<t<\tau$.

Comment: Thanks alot @shuhao cao

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider $\int_\infty^\infty \int_0^t u_s ds dx $.

Comment: What is $u_s$ in your hint and could you maybe elaborate on the idea?

Comment: @user76189 $u_s$ is the same as $u_t$, you need a different name to avoid name clash.

Comment: @MaMing Integral solution to the conservation laws is not generally differentiable, and you can't do this.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao I am too naïve, good to know your solution.

Comment: @MaMing No you are not, for smooth solution, your method works! Sorry for being rude for the previous comment, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the spatial mollification
\begin{align}
&u^\varepsilon(x,t)=\int_\mathbb{R} \eta_\varepsilon(x-y)u(y,t)dy,
\end{align}
which has compact support.
Let $\varphi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}\times[0,\infty))$ be a smooth test function; we compute
\begin{align}
I=&\iint_{t>0} u^\varepsilon_t \varphi dxdt=-\iint_{t>0}u^\varepsilon\varphi_tdxdt-\int_\mathbb{R} u^\varepsilon(x,0)\varphi(x,0) dx\label{eq1} \\
=&-\int_0^\infty\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} \eta_\varepsilon(x-y)u(y,t)\varphi_t(x,t)dydxdt-\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} \eta_\varepsilon(x-y)u(y,0)\varphi(x,0)dydx\\
=&-\int_0^\infty\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} \eta(y-x)u(y,t)\varphi_t(x,t)dxdydt-\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} \eta_\varepsilon(y-x)g(y)\varphi(x,0)dxdy\\
=&-\int_0^\infty\int_\mathbb{R} \varphi^\varepsilon_t(y,t)u(y,t)dydt-\int_\mathbb{R} \varphi^\varepsilon(y,0)g(y)dy\\
=&-\iint_{t>0}u\varphi^\varepsilon_t dxdt-\int_\mathbb{R} g\varphi^\varepsilon(\cdot,0)dx,\\
\end{align}
where we used Fubini's theorem and integration by parts. Since $u$ is an integral solution we get that $I$ is equal to
\begin{align}
&\iint_{t>0}F(u)\varphi^\varepsilon_xdxdt= \int_0^\infty\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} \eta_\varepsilon(x-y)F(u(x,t))\varphi_x(y,t)dydxdt\\
=&\int_0^\infty\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} \eta_\varepsilon(y-x)F(u(x,t))\varphi_x(y,t)dxdydt\\
=&\int_{0}^\infty \int_\mathbb{R} (F\circ u)^\varepsilon(y,t) \varphi_x(y,t)dydt\\
=&-\iint_{t>0} (F\circ u)^\varepsilon_x\varphi dxdt+\int_0^\infty \bigg|_{y=-\infty}^{\infty} (F\circ u)^\varepsilon(y,t) \varphi(y,t)dt\\
=&-\iint_{t>0}(F\circ u)^\varepsilon_x\varphi dxdt.
\end{align}
Therefore $u^\varepsilon$ solves the equation $u^\varepsilon_t +(F\circ u)^\varepsilon_x=0$ in $\mathbb{R}\times [0,\infty)$. Now
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\int_\mathbb{R} u^\varepsilon(x,t)dx&=\int_\mathbb{R} -(F\circ u)^\varepsilon_x(x,t)dx=0.
\end{align}
Therefore for all $t>0$ we have
\begin{align}
\int_\mathbb{R} u^\varepsilon(x,t)dx=\int_\mathbb{R} u^\varepsilon (x,0)dx.
\end{align}
Since $u$ has compact support, the statement follows by taking $\varepsilon\to 0$.